# SSMS Open Query SQL Command Not Properly Ended

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
select
    *
from
    OPENQUERY
    (
        [xxx], 'SELECT * FROM table'
    ) as S
```

I don't understand why I am getting the error message `SQL command not properly ended`.

Any suggestions?

**Edit #1:**

The database I am using (xxx) is a snowflake database.

**Edit #2:**

This query works:

```
SELECT 
    S.[col_1]
    ,S.[col_2]
    ,*
FROM 
    OPENQUERY
    (
        [xxx], 'SELECT * FROM schema.table_a'
    ) as S
where
    S.[col_1] = 'whatever';
```

But I don't understand why this query doesn't:

```
SELECT 
    S.*
FROM 
    OPENQUERY
    (
        [xxx], 'SELECT * FROM schema.table_a'
    ) as S
where
    S.[col_1] = 'whatever';
```

Comment: That is neither an SSMS nor a SQL Server error, but likely the result of server `xxx` when presented with `SELECT * FROM table` (searching suggests Oracle is a likely candidate). Oracle should not normally complain about a trivial query, so check your linked server definition. Also check your query for invisible characters; retype it if necessary.

Comment: Is that the exact statement that produces the error?  Obviously the server name is obfuscated, what about the SQL?  Your example is clearly valid SQL syntax, even for Oracle.  Oracle throws that error if your SQL statement ends with a bad clause or something like that.  My guess is that you're simplifying the SQL for the sake of the question and that the original query has an error in it.

Comment: If the remote server is Oracle, try adding a semicolon to the end of the quoted SELECT command.  Oracle is kind of weird about when it does/does not require one (depends on what interface you are entering Oracle from).

Comment: Not a Snowflake expert, but I think Snowflake does require a semicolon at the end of a statement.

Comment: I am quite puzzled as to why you would be receiving an Oracle error to a query made from SQL Server to a Snowflake database.  At this point, I think that we need to see the actually query being made, obfuscate the table name, but do not simplify anything.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo when I was editing, removed the first comma in the 2nd non-working query.

Comment: Try changing `S.*` to just `*`.

Comment: Tried that, still got error.